# "Whitelabel Error Page" when using SpringDoc with Kotlin and WebFlux

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux, springdoc

I am getting `Whitelabel Error Page` when using the SpringBoot + Kotlin + SpringDoc + WebFlux. No documentation is generated despite dependencies from offical springdoc documentation page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMkJu.png).

`application.yaml` does not contain any properties specified

```
private object Version {
  const val kotlinCoroutinesVersion = "1.6.4"
  const val openApiVersion = "1.6.12"
}

plugins {
  val kotlinVersion = "1.8.10"

  id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.0.2"
  id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
  id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring") version kotlinVersion
}


dependencies {

  // Coroutines dependencies
  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:${Version.kotlinCoroutinesVersion}")
  runtimeOnly("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor:${Version.kotlinCoroutinesVersion}")

  // Spring dependencies
  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")

  // Swagger
  implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:${Version.openApiVersion}")
  implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-kotlin:${Version.openApiVersion}")

  // Validation
  implementation("javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final")
}
```

Example Controller looks like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/product")
internal class OrderController(
  private val orderCommand: OrderCommand
) {

  @PostMapping
  suspend fun saveProduct(@Valid @RequestBody createOrderRequest: CreateOrderRequest): ResponseEntity<OrderCreatedResponse> {
    // Some code
}
```

Main function:

```
@EnableWebFlux
@SpringBootApplication
class Application


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  SpringApplication.run(Application::class.java, *args)
}
```

Any ideas what can I missed? I checked locally on localhost:8080/v3/api-docs.yaml and localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html but still no page has been generated

Comment: try openApiVersion 2.0.2

Comment: what you missed was to post your full debug logs here that will tell you straight out what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-graphql")
```

to dependencies solved the issue